# If I choose "Revert to" menu item on the Ubuntu Grub boot menu, is that irreversible?

Tags: grub2, zfs

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 with ZFS full-disk encryption. When I boot up, I'm presented with these options (in Grub):

```
Ubuntu 21.10
Advanced options for Ubuntu 21.10
History for Ubuntu 21.10
EUFI Firmware Settings
```

If I choose "History for Ubuntu 21.10", I am presented with options like these:

```
Revert to 15/10/21 @ 12:14
Revert to 15/10/21 @ 11:22
Revert to Ubuntu 21.04 on 15/10/21 @ 08:46
Revert to Ubuntu 21.05 on 14/10/21 @ 17:25
```

If I select one of these options, I get presented these options:

```
Revert system only
Revert system and user data
Revert system only (recovery mode)
Revert system and user data (recovery mode)
```

My question is: what happens when I select one of the revert options? Will the filesystem be reverted to an older state irreversibly? Can I go back to the newer state?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm having just attempted a recovery using this option on Ubuntu 20.04 with rpool (for user and root) and bpool (for boot), that when you select "Revert system and user data" it will boot to the desktop that was snapshot at that time. Then after successful boot it appeared to make a new snapshot. After a subsequent reboot it continued on from the new snapshot that was based on the rollback to the recovery snapshot. I was careful to verify that I had valid snapshots on bpool and rpool for all nodes before attempting the restore and was pleasantly surprised by how well it worked. I hope anyone else who gives it a try is as successful. Also the (recovery mode) appears to boot to  recovery console instead of the full desktop, I didn't try it but that was the impression I got from looking at the source code.